# Syntax question for delayed_jobs and email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, delayed-job

I am getting a beautiful error :

```
failed with NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[] - 3 failed attempts
```

**My Controller:**

```
CardSignup.all.each do |user|
  Delayed::Job.enqueue MassEmail.new(user, params[:subject], params[:editor1])
end
```

**mass_email.rb**

```
class MassEmail < Struct.new(:user, :subject, :message)
  def perform
    Notifier.deliver_email_blast(user, subject, message)
  end
end
```

**_form.html.haml**

```
- form_tag admin_email_blast_path do
  Subject
  %br
  = text_field_tag 'subject'
  %br
  Body
  %br
  = text_area_tag 'message', '', :name => 'editor1'
  %br
  = submit_tag 'Send Email', :class => 'button'

  :plain
    <script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
    </script>
```

The problem is because i'm not passing the varis right.. how do I do this proper?

**note:** It was working perfectly before i implemented delayed_jobs with params[:subject], and params[:editor1], so I have to retain those somehow.

I tried this without Delayed_Jobs, and the MassEmail.new doesn't even leave a backtrace in my log.

I also tried this in my console, and it froze.

There's got to be something wrong with the mass_email.rb or the call in `def perform`

Comment: it would be nice to know where the `NoMethodError` gets raised.

Comment: How do I find that? This is what precursored it 2010-09-14T11:57:18-0400: * [Worker(delayed_job host:Daniel-Levines-iMac-3.local pid:754)] acquired lock on MassEmail
2010-09-14T11:57:18-0400: * [JOB] delayed_job host:Daniel-Levines-iMac-3.local pid:754

Comment: sorry, but this is not helpful. Normally you get a full backtrace and near the ErrorMeassage must be something like this: `some_path/some_file.rb:213`.

Comment: Yah..even when i took it out of delayed jobs, it doesn't even report an error. Crazy, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos to JigFox for getting me to write the params right.

And I'm not entirely sure why this works, but I moved the loop into the MassEmail.new function.

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue MassEmail.new(params[:subject], params[:editor1])

class MassEmail < Struct.new(:subject, :editor1)
  def perform
    CardSignup.all.each do |user|
      Notifier.deliver_email_blast(user, subject, editor1)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitively wrong, you gave two parameters the same name:

```
class MassEmail < Struct.new(:user, :params, :params)
```

How does the perform method now which param you're referring to?

You can try something like this

```
class MassEmail < Struct.new(:user, :subject, :editor1)
  def perform
    Notifier.deliver_email_blast(user, subject, editor1)
  end
end
```

Comment: Well at least its a step up in syntax. But it still returns the same error. I'd give a better trace, but its failing through delayed_jobs.

Comment: I think its erroring because the vars i'm calling from my form in my MassEmail.new can't be passed through ?